# Loading 22 Mil + records into neo4j database via databricks environment

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, databricks, azure-databricks, neo4j-apoc

I am using neo4j spark connector and via databricks environment  - I have loaded 22 Mil records into neo4j  database and While establishing relationships for this 22mil records with the query

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('Match (jh:JournalHeader) return jh', 
  'with jh MATCH (jli:JournalLineItem) where jli.glheader_id = jh.glheader_id  MERGE (jh)-[:HAS_PARENT]->(jli)', 
  {batchSize:1000, parallel:false}) 
yield batch return null;")
```

Though the required relationships got established in neo4j database. The spark job is hanging and no updates are being written.

Is there a way to make the query more efficient so once the relationships got established it will finish the job. Because in this case though the relationships got established still the query is searching for all the other records which is not necessary in this case

Comment: I used a web-hosted files to import my big data into neo4j aura. You might found something here that can help you. Goodluck! https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/